# Add number of days in Oracle DB using SQL in java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot

I am using below SQL in java code to update date in Oracle DB.

```
UPDATE CUS_LOGS SET START_DATE=to_date(systimestamp + 3,'DD-MON-RRRR'), END_DATE=to_date(systimestamp + 21921,'DD-MON-RRRR')  
WHERE CUS_ID IN ('9b90cb8175ba0ca60175ba12d8711006');
```

My expectation is:

```
START_DATE = 05-NOV-2022 
END_DATE = 08-NOV-2082.
```

However the result I see as

```
START_DATE = 05-NOV-2022 
END_DATE = 08-NOV-1982    **********
```

Apparently issue happens when the date pass `31-12-2049`. i.e. adding `+ 9922` as of today (02/11/2022)

Comment: @Abra `RRRR` and `YYYY` give same result. Further both columns data type is `DATE`. If I run the query directly in SQL developer it gives the expected result.

Comment: I doubt they give the same result - YYYY should give 08-NOV-0082, which is still wrong but much more so. You're seeing different results in Spring vs SQL Developer because your database sessions have different NLS settings - which is why you should never rely on them.

Comment: @AlexPoole Sorry, You're correct `YYYY` gives `08-NOV-0082`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're relying on implicit conversion, which is using your NLS settings, which are formatting dates as string with 2-digit years.

If your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is `DD-MON-RR` or `DD-MON-YY` then doing

```
to_date(systimestamp + 3,'DD-MON-RRRR')
```

is really doing something like:

```
to_date(to_char(cast(systimestamp as date) + 3,'DD-MON-RR','DD-MON-RRRR')
```

which means it tries to convert the string '08-NOV-82' to a date using the mask 'DD-MON-RRRR'. The [RRRR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F) means that a 2-digit year like 82 is interpreted as 1982 - which is what you're seeing. Using `DD-MON-YYYY` would be even worse, as that would interpret 82 as 0082.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR'
```

```
select
  to_date(sysdate + 3,'DD-MON-RRRR') as a,
  to_char(to_date(sysdate + 3,'DD-MON-RRRR'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as b,
  to_date(sysdate + 21921,'DD-MON-RRRR') c,
  to_char(to_date(sysdate + 21921,'DD-MON-RRRR'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d,
  to_date(sysdate + 3,'DD-MON-YYYY') as e,
  to_char(to_date(sysdate + 3,'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as f,
  to_date(sysdate + 21921,'DD-MON-YYYY') as g,
  to_char(to_date(sysdate + 21921,'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as h
from dual
```

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05-NOV-22 | 2022-11-05 | 08-NOV-82 | 1982-11-08 | 05-NOV-22 | 0022-11-05 | 08-NOV-82 | 0082-11-08 |

So you would need to explicitly convert the date to a string with a 4-digit year, then convert it back again...

But you don't need to do any of that conversion. Just adding the number of days to the timestamp - which implicitly converts *that* to a date, but safely - gets the result you want:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR'
```

```
select systimestamp,
  systimestamp + 3,
  systimestamp + 21921
from dual
```

| SYSTIMESTAMP | SYSTIMESTAMP+3 | SYSTIMESTAMP+21921 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-02 10:42:24 +00:00 | 2022-11-05 | 2082-11-08 |

There's no point using `systimestamp` here though, you can avoid even that implicit conversion by using `sysdate`:

```
select sysdate,
  sysdate + 3,
  sysdate + 21921
from dual
```

| SYSDATE | SYSDATE+3 | SYSDATE+21921 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-05 | 2082-11-08 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kz0JmOH9)

You seem to be doing the conversion in order to remove the time portion of the current date/time - or, more correctly, set it to midnight as a date always has a time. But you can do that with `trunc()`.

So, in summary, your update statement should just be:

```
UPDATE CUS_LOGS SET START_DATE=trunc(sysdate) + 3, END_DATE=trunc(sysdate) + 21921
WHERE CUS_ID IN ('9b90cb8175ba0ca60175ba12d8711006');
```

Your end date is roughly 60 years ahead; you might want to use `add_months(trunc(sysdate), 60*12)` and then add any additional days to that - maybe just keeping the `+ 3`, inside or outside the `add_months()`, or both; `add_months(trunc(sysdate) + 3, 60*12) + 3` would give the same result as `+ 21921`, today anyway. But it isn't clear exactly what you're doing...

And you can add intervals rather than a number of days, which is a bit more explicit; but that works less well for adding months/years because it can lead to invalid-date errors, e.g. if you try to add a year interval to Feb 29th.

Comment: Just curious why this happens in my question scenario, when the date pass `31-12-2049`. i.e. adding `+ 9922` (i.e. if the current date is 02/11/2022). That means if I add any number < 9922 gives the correct value. The year becomes `1950` after `31-12-2049`

Comment: That's what [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F) says, in the bullets and the examples. 00-49 are treated as this century, 50-99 are previous century.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query and prevent issues from implicit timestamp-to-date-to-string conversions (as [described by @Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74287982/1509264)) using:

```sql
UPDATE CUS_LOGS
SET   START_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '3' DAY,
      END_DATE   = ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 60*12) + INTERVAL '6' DAY 
WHERE CUS_ID     = '9b90cb8175ba0ca60175ba12d8711006';
```